# Highlight spots in PDF documents that are embeded in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Employees need to check data imported using OCR. They have web interface showing imported data on the left side and the scanned image on the right. When dealing with a large list of items they get lost and are asking for a tool/pen able to highlight (PDF) rows that are already checked.

Is there any chance to use JavaScript and draw to the PDF that is viewed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are viewing the PDF in a plug-in, the answer is no, not through JS.

If, however, you can leverage a tool like [**pdf.js**](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js), this may be possible, depending on what your document uses in terms of PDF elements. For example, `pdf.js` has an `Annotation` plug-in, which looks like it may enable you to actually create annotations.

You will not be able to save the changes, however. If you want to do this, you are strongly encouraged to use a proper UI and not just a PDF (though, you may read from the PDF to generate it).

Comment: I'm using Adobe Reader. The annotations are needed just temporarily, to help the user keep the eye on the checked rows.

Comment: @user1517081: Might want to try `pdf.js`. It should be seamless, and from there, a tiny amount of JS will allow you to finish this. Bear in mind, `pdf.js` renders to Canvas, so you **can** write on it. Adobe Reader has annotations if you prefer to avoid js/switching - but you'll have to teach your employees to use that :-)